# Retro computers and "jail bars" on the screen

Tags: output, video

I have tried to eliminate "jail bars" on the screen after UHF mod to video out (based on that: http://zx81stuff.org.uk/zx81/ts1500_video.html) by adding 460uf 16V capacitor between +5V and GND but it didn't do anything to reduce them.

Any thought on that?

This is how it looks on the screen:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you may be talking about the difference between interlaced and progressive mode operation? (p vs i.) A retro computer for NTSC would be targeting an interlaced TV and would add half a scan line to both fields. (There are 262.5 scan lines per field for a total of 525 scan lines.) Some receivers do recognize the extra half line as sufficient to switch to interlaced mode, automatically. Some don't and may require an added blob of memory-buffered hardware for this. (A de-interlacer of some kind.) A picture of what you see might be nice, though.

Comment: @jonk I have updated my question with the picture of those "jail bars"

Comment: that looks like the "text character" clock breaking through into the video ....... did you try to turn down the `contrast` setting?

Comment: Possibly a dried-up/bad electrolytic capacitor in the scan derived power supply for the video or chroma circuits. See if you can find the ripple using a scope. Or just replace the electrolytics.

Comment: @jsotola turning down `contrast` did nothing in this case

Comment: @jonk problem is that there is no capacitors between video circuit (ULA chip in this case) and +5V for power supply for that circuit that is why I have tried to add 460uf

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect a capacitor to eliminate those bars.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It came from another forum where they have talked about "softening" Vcc

Comment: Overshoot on video. Could be that 460uf is too big. Try 0.1uf in parallel. Could also be inductance in wires - keep them short, especially ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 'jail-bars' appear to be a synchronous subset of the horizontal trace. They are very clean and well defined. Suggest tracking down horizontal circuits and replacing the electrolytics in just that section.

If problem still exist try to find a point where you can modify just the vertical bars and nothing else.

At some point you may stumble into a leaky transistor or bad IC. Bad resistors and capacitors tend to open up and loose value, so check those in the horizontal section.